# Invalid JSON List<map<string, string>> in JAVA

Tags: java, json, list

I have in JAVA this: `private Map<String,String> car;`

Then other class the map will be transformed to a list of maps like this

```
List<Map<String,String>> car;

 and then here is the implementation

 List<Map<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
 CarEvidence.getCarFieldsEvidence().forEach((key, value) -> {
            mylist.add(new HashMap<String,String>(){{
                put("field",key);
                put("value",value);
            }});
        });
```

How do I transform this to a JSON object? Id I send this to the services throws an error, invalid json.

......"other JSON Parameters".......

```
 "mylist": [
            {
              "field": "unique",
              "secondValue": "pontiac",
              "value": "10000"
            },
            {
              "field": "other",
              "secondValue": null,
              "value": "any value"
            },
            {
              "field": "log",
              "secondValue": null,
              "value": "contract"
            },
            {
              "field": "message",
              "secondValue": null,
              "value": "last value"
            }
          ]
```

But if I send this the services returns 200 ok

```
"mylist": 
        {
          "field": "firstValue",
          "secondValue": null,
          "value": ""
        }
```

Please, help :(

Comment: Well, apparently, the endpoint does not expect `myList` to be a list, but rather a single object.

Comment: Using `HashMap` is completely pointless in that situation; just use `ArrayList<SomeModel>`.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding JSON for `List<Map<String,String>>` is given below

```
[
            {
              "field": "unique",
              "secondValue": "pontiac",
              "value": "10000"
            },
            {
              "field": "other",
              "secondValue": null,
              "value": "any value"
            },
            {
              "field": "log",
              "secondValue": null,
              "value": "contract"
            },
            {
              "field": "message",
              "secondValue": null,
              "value": "last value"
            }
          ]
```

The reason why it sends 200 when you send

```
"mylist": 
        {
          "field": "firstValue",
          "secondValue": null,
          "value": ""
        }
```

is because, the key in the map is taken as "mylist" and the value as String of json

Answer (score 0):

JSON always starts with a `{` and ends with a `}` ...which means, you have to set `myList` as property on some object, which then should be properly encoded. Add the curly brackets and you'd see it will parse: https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser